# Merge two columns as single column in same table

Tags: mysql

**CA_ID**                **SPA_ID**

```
   1        NULL 
   2        NULL
   NULL      1
   NULL      2
```

i need to merge above two headers as single column but null values must be removed like this shown below

**TYPE**

```
  1
  2
  1
  2
```

Comment: `SELECT CA_ID FROM mytable WHERE CA_ID IS NOT NULL UNION ALL SELECT SPA_ID FROM mytable WHERE SPA_ID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: its working tq...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, using `UNION`:

```
SELECT CA_ID AS 'TYPE' FROM table_name WHERE NOT CA_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT SPA_ID AS 'TYPE' FROM table_name WHERE NOT SPA_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Its a great answer!!